# How can I use ajax.reload with jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a requirement to make a search form that will call a web api and populate a jQuery DataTable when a button is clicked. I don't want to load the form until the button is clicked so I have a separate button handler to call my post method. I was told I should use ajax.reload() with this in case someone has to search again to narrow the results but am having some trouble working it into my code. Can anyone assist me with my requirement? My code works fine as is but I would like to know if it can be done more efficiently. See my working code below.

```
<script>
    var dataTable;
    var resultsContainer = $('#ResultsContainer');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      dataTable = $('#SearchResultsTable').DataTable({
        "columns": [
          { "data": "clientId" },
          { "data": "lastName"   },
          { "data": "firstName"  }
        ],
        "language": {
          "zeroRecords": '@Resource.NoRecordsFound'
        },
        "searching": false,
        "lengthChange": false
      });
    });

    $('#SearchButton').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      RequestData();
    });

    function RequestData() {
      $.post('@Url.Content("?handler=ClientSearch")', $('#ClientSearchForm').serialize(), function (data) {
        ProcessResponse(data);
      });
    }

    function ProcessResponse(data) {  
        dataTable.clear();
        dataTable.rows.add(data);
        dataTable.draw();
        resultsContainer.addClass('d-block');
    }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DataTable `ajax.reload` method requires the URL for the data to be defined.  In the example on https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload, they use the `ajax` option in the configuration object to set the URL:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );
```

Then calls to `table.ajax.reload()` will just pull the updated data in from `data.json` again.  In your case, you're doing a POST to retrieve the data with the search form.  So you'll either need to:

- use a jQuery ajax object as the value of your DataTable `ajax` option (see https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object); or
- Set `ajax.url` (https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url) with each search form submission

Hope that helps.